# Как работают интерфейсы в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, интерфейс

Код взят из книги http://habrahabr.ru/post/241587/. Насколько я понял, в JS нет понятия интерфейса, как в Java. Но автор книги пишет комментарий к коду:

> Программа будет общаться с объектами ячеек через хорошо определённый интерфейс. Типы ячеек не будут заданы жёстко. Мы сможем добавлять
>   новые стили ячеек – к примеру, подчёркнутые ячейки у заголовка. И если
>   они будут поддерживать наш интерфейс, они просто заработают, без
>   изменений в программе. Интерфейс:
>
> minHeight() возвращает число, показывающее минимальную высоту, которую
>   требует ячейка (выраженную в строчках)
>
> minWidth() возвращает число, показывающее минимальную ширину, которую
>   требует ячейка (выраженную в символах)
>
> draw(width, height) возвращает массив длины height, содержащий наборы
>   строк, каждая из которых шириной в width символов. Это содержимое
>   ячейки.

Далее код:

```js
function rowHeights(rows) {
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(max, cell) {
      return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
    }, 0);
  });
}

function colWidths(rows) {
  return rows[0].map(function(_, i) {
    return rows.reduce(function(max, row) {
      return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

Я понимаю, какую роль играет max и cell, как работают map и reduce. Но не понимаю что в данном случае делает .minHeight(), minWidth(), draw() ? Что это - интерфейс или все-таки метод? Если это просто метод, то где код, который выполняется при его вызове?

В следующем куске кода снова встречаются эти методы:

```js
function UnderlinedCell(inner) {
  this.inner = inner;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minWidth = function() {
  return this.inner.minWidth();
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minHeight = function() {
  return this.inner.minHeight() + 1;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.draw = function(width, height) {
  return this.inner.draw(width, height - 1)
    .concat([repeat("-", width)]);
};
```

Т.е. `UnderlinedCell.prototype.minWidth` и есть описание этого метода, а `return this.inner.minWidth();` - это рекурсия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, подразумевается что `UnderlinedCell.prototype.minWidth` и будет определять интерфейс объекта. Так же (в отличии от классических интерфейсов) эти интерфейсы содержат реализацию, которая в данном случае просто прокидывает вызов на объект `inner` (который был принят в контруктор) но могут быть и другие реализации интерфейсов.

Объект `UnderlinedCell` гарантирует что он имеет методы подсчета ширины и высоты ячейки а так же сможет её нарисовать. Но конкретная реализация этих алгоритмов лежит уже на объекте `inner`. А значит объект `UnderlinedCell` должен убедиться что реализующий его объект имеет требуемые методы.

Таким образом получается Объект-интерфейс который гарантирует объявленное поведение и не содержит алгоритмов реализующих это поведение. А объект `inner` реализует этот интерфейс.

Возможна и другая реализация интерфейсов в javascript:

http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/14657-interfejjsy-v-javascript.html
http://jscriptpatterns.blogspot.ru/2013/01/javascript-interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

В JavaScript нет интерфейсов, но вы можете их выдумать при желании. В общем случае "интерфейс" значит "договор" или "контракт". Есть языки где такие контракты присутствуют в явном виде и проверяются на выполнение компилятором. В JavaScript таких конструкций нет. Поэтому в вашем контексте это просто договоренность о том какие методы будут и что они должны делать.